# Unable to validate Weblogic domain" - Oracle Enterprise Pack

Tags: eclipse, dns, weblogic

I have been facing the "Unable to validate Weblogic domain" issue from OEPE for last 2 days. I have tried 
(a) downloading and installing different versions of OEPE ; 
(b) Using Eclipse and Oracle Weblogic separately ; outside of OEPE etc

It used to work previously and then one day last week, my system shut down unexpectedly and since then I am not able to get Eclipse (irrespective of version) and Weblogic to work together.

I have moved on to using Jboss for the time being. But since my production environment is Weblogic and I would like to use Weblogic for development purposes as well, I am trying to get this issue resolved.

I did search the Oracle and other communities and somebody mentioned its because of difference in java version and to add 
-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true

in eclipse.ini. My eclipse.ini already has this statement and I still face the issue.Please help.

Comment: Is the java version you're using in eclipse the same as Weblogic? You haven't posted those details or the full stack trace

Comment: Both are working on java version 1.6. There are no exceptions in the log files. Log file indicates that the serevr has started. However, eclipse does not recognize it as being started.

Comment: I finally got the resolution for this issue. Actually the full credit goes to my colleague, who resolved this bugging bug. 

Since it drove me crazy, decided that I would spare others from the same experience 
First of all, there were no errors in any of the logs. Server was starting up but Eclipse did not recognize it as such.

And here is the resolution :
Go to Window Tab -> Preferences -> General -> Network Connections
Change the Active provider to "Direct". The default is usually Native.  and that's  it. Close and restart eclipse.

Comment: actually, kudos to the solution you already tried - it worked for me :)

Answer (score 6):

Iam not the person who answers this question. But the comment above is the answer for this question and it worked for me too. Below is the solution.

*I finally got the resolution for this issue. Actually the full credit goes to my colleague, who resolved this bugging bug. Since it drove me crazy, decided that I would spare others from the same experience First of all, there were no errors in any of the logs. Server was starting up but Eclipse did not recognize it as such. And here is the resolution : Go to Window Tab -> Preferences -> General -> Network Connections Change the Active provider to "Direct". The default is usually Native. and that's it. Close and restart eclipse.*

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me as well, I even reinstalled weblogic again, after a bit of research I decided to kill the Java(TM) Platform SE Binary process via Task Manager and restarted the Server.

That's all It took to resolve the issue.